# Interface ou instância de um generic

Tags: flutter, dart

## Interface

Queria utilizar interface no Dart, mas depois de muita pesquisar, descobrir que não há, então fiz da seguinte maneira, criei uma classe abstrata:

```
abstract class IModel {
  String _uid;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();

  IModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json);

  String get uid => _uid;

  set uid(String value) {
    _uid = value;
  }
}
```

E a implementei desta forma:

```
import 'package:whatsapp/services/model/imodel.dart';

class UserModel implements IModel {

  @override
  String uid;

  String _name;
  String _email;

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {"name": _name, "email": _email};

  @override
  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    uid = json["uid"];
    _name = json["name"];
    _email = json["email"];
  }

  String get email => _email;

  set email(String value) {
    _email = value;
  }

  String get name => _name;

  set name(String value) {
    _name = value;
  }

}
```

## Generic

Então criei a seguinte classe para gerenciar o Firebase:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/services/model/imodel.dart';

import '../firestore_service.dart';

class BaseService<T extends IModel> extends FirestoreService {
  BaseService(String path) : super(path);

  @override
  Future<List<T>> GetAll() async {
    List<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshotList = await GetAllDocuments();
    documentSnapshotList.map((item) => _fromJson(item));
  }

  Future<T> GetById(String id) async {
    return _fromJson(await GetDocumentById(id));
  }

  Future<String> Create(T model) async =>
      (await CreateDocument(model.toJson())).documentID;

  Future<String> CreateOrUpdate(T model) => model.uid == null
      ? Create(model)
      : CreateOrUpdateDocument(model.uid, model.toJson());

  Future<void> Delete(String id) => DeleteDocument(id);

  T _fromJson(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    var newItem = snapshot.data;
    newItem["uid"] = snapshot.documentID;
    return T.fromJson(newItem);
  }
}
```

A principio queria utilizar uma interface para resolver este problema, no lugar do "T" utilizaria a interface, então decidir usar o generic, tudo funcionou bem até eu precisar instanciar "T":

```
return T.fromJson(newItem);
```

Tenho o seguinte erro:

```
Compiler message:
lib/services/model/base_service.dart:31:14: Error: The method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the class 'Type'.
 - 'Type' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fromJson'.
    return T.fromJson(newItem);
             ^^^^^^^^
```

## Resumo

Pesquisei e não encontrei nenhuma forma de instanciar um generic ou criar uma interface, minha ideia é criar uma classe base para gerenciar o Firebase e só passar a classe que será persistida.

> Obs: O engraçado é que informo que meu "T" é um "IModel":
>
> ```
> BaseService<T extends IModel>
> ```
>
> E mesmo assim ele não reconhece "fromJson" de "IModel".

Comment: Flutter não possuí reflection, parece que até da para implementar, mas não fica muito legal.

Comment: Eu até tentei, mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 3):

## Aviso

Esta não é a resposta que procuro, esta foi a melhor solução que encontrei até o momento, vou postar como resposta que talvez ajude alguém, não esta bom, mas é melhor do que nada.

## Solução parcial

Faço o *extends* da classe "BaseService" e passo um método estático no construtor, este método cria uma nova instancia de "UserModel".

```
import 'package:whatsapp/services/model/user_model.dart';

import 'model/base_service.dart';

class UserService extends BaseService<UserModel> {
  UserService._constructor() : super("usuarios", NewInstance);

  static final UserService _instance = UserService._constructor();

  factory UserService() {
    return _instance;
  }

  static UserModel NewInstance(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel.fromJson(json);

}
```

E na classe "BaseService" eu chamo este método como uma function, solucionando o problema da nova instancia:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/services/model/imodel.dart';

import '../firestore_service.dart';

class BaseService<T extends IModel> extends FirestoreService {
  Function(Map<String, dynamic> json) _newInstance;

  BaseService(String path, Function(Map<String, dynamic> json) newInstance)
      : super(path) {
    _newInstance = newInstance;
  }

  @override
  Future<List<T>> GetAll() async {
    List<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshotList = await GetAllDocuments();
    documentSnapshotList.map((item) => _fromJson(item));
  }

  Future<T> GetById(String id) async {
    return _fromJson(await GetDocumentById(id));
  }

  Future<String> Create(T model) async =>
      (await CreateDocument(model.toJson())).documentID;

  Future<String> CreateOrUpdate(T model) => model.uid == null
      ? Create(model)
      : CreateOrUpdateDocument(model.uid, model.toJson());

  Future<void> Delete(String id) => DeleteDocument(id);

  T _fromJson(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    var newItem = snapshot.data;
    newItem["uid"] = snapshot.documentID;
    return _newInstance(newItem);
  }
}
```

## Resumo

Esta não é a melhor solução, não é tão intuitivo quanto uma interface ou generic, contudo ajuda a não repetir o mesmo código para cada service.

Answer (score 3):

Estava procurando algo do tipo e encontrei uma outra forma, nesse método a instância é criada via Funcion e chamada via callback.

Nos teste notei que o intellisense (autocomplete) fica prejudicado nos métodos onde o tipo genérico é utilizado (`T getById(String id) {`), mas não atrapalha tanto.

```
typedef S ObjectCreator<S>();
//typedef ObjectCreator<S> = S Function(); 

class BaseService<T extends IModel> {
  BaseService(this.creator);
  final ObjectCreator<T> creator;

  //get _t => creator();

  T getById(String id) {
    final _t = creator();
.......
```

A instancia via generic fica assim:

```
BaseService<UserModel>(() => UserModel());
```

Segue código exemplo ou veja rodando no [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b6b70842d3a1292c6024df456b1aebbb):

```
class FirestoreServiceMock {}

abstract class IModel {
  String _uid;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();

  fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json);

  String get uid => _uid;

  set uid(String value) {
    _uid = value;
  }
}

class UserModel implements IModel {
  @override
  String uid;

  String _name;
  String _email;

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {"name": _name, "email": _email};

  @override
  fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    uid = json["uid"];
    _name = json["name"];
    _email = json["email"];
  }

  String get email => _email;

  set email(String value) {
    _email = value;
  }

  String get name => _name;

  set name(String value) {
    _name = value;
  }

  @override
  String _uid;
}

typedef S ObjectCreator<S>();

class BaseService<T extends IModel> {
  BaseService(this.creator);
  final ObjectCreator<T> creator;

  T getById(String id) {
    final t = creator();

    final fakeData = {
      'uid': '5',
      'name': 'Maria',
      'email': 'maria@maria.com',
    };

    t.fromJson(fakeData);
    return t;
  }
}

void main() {
  var b = BaseService<UserModel>(() => UserModel());
  var user = b.getById('1');
  print('Id: ${user.uid} Usuario: ${user.name} Email: ${user.email}');
  //
}
```

Baseado nesta resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112130/creating-an-instance-of-a-generic-type-in-dart